# Regex to replace iframe with youtube link from iframes src in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a text that contains possible multiple `iframes`, and what I intend to do is take the src from that iframe, and replace the whole iframe with just the text in that src.

As an example, if I have this:

```
Some text here. After that, an iframe: <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/GplWFSU3tLA"></iframe>
```

I want to have this:

```
Some text here. After that, an iframe: //www.youtube.com/embed/GplWFSU3tLA
```

This is what I've tried doing: I have written a regexp for iframe and a regexp for a youtube link. Then I take the text I want to parse, I use `.replace` to replace all the iframes, and inside the function I pass `x` that matched the iframe, and run the youtube regexp to find only the youtube link, after which I return the link (which should in theory replace the matched iframe).

I suspect I have either written one or both of the `RegExp` poorly, or I am using `.replace` in a wrong way. Thanks for any insights!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var iframeHunter = new RegExp(/<iframe(.+)<\/iframe>/g);
  var youtubeLinkHunter = new RegExp(/(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+/mgi);
  
  var message_text = $("#textHolder").text();
  
  message_text = message_text.replace(iframeHunter, function myFunction(x){
         var youtubeLink = x.match(youtubeLinkHunter);
         return youtubeLink;
      });
  
  $("#replacedOutput").text(message_text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Text being parsed:
<p id="textHolder">Some text here. After that, an iframe: <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/GplWFSU3tLA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
Output:
<p id="replacedOutput"></p>
```

I've also recreated it in jsfiddle, with the same code as above: https://jsfiddle.net/e5vgscq0/

**Edit for clarification:** I do not need to replace the DOM iframe element with a youtube link, I need a new string where all the iframes have been replaced with youtube srcs.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set an ID on the iframe.

```html
<iframe id="some-id" ...></iframe>
```

In your jsfiddle set `LOAD TYPE` to `No wrap - bottom of <body>`

```js
const theIFrame = document.getElementById("some-id")

document.getElementById("replacedOutput").textContent = theIFrame.src;
```

Otherwise using regEx.

```
(www.youtube.com\/embed\/)(\w+)
```

```
<p id="textHolder">Som
e text here. After that, an iframe:  <iframe id="some-id" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/GplWFSU3tLA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</p>
```

```
const textHolder = document.getElementById("textHolder").innerHTML;
// Remove g to find first match only
const regEx = /(www.youtube.com\/embed\/)(\w+)/g
const match = textHolder.match(regEx);

// Note match will return an array for every match it finds.
// [0] www.youtube.com/embed/GplWFSU3tLA
console.log(match);
```

---

Ignore below

[0] Full Match `www.youtube.com/embed/GplWFSU3tLA`
[1] Group 1 `www.youtube.com/embed/`
[2] Group 2 `GplWFSU3tLA`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer! How should I reference Group 2 so I can return it in the place of the iframe?